# Monotonic increasing function with constraints

Tags: trigonometry, exponential-function, ceiling-and-floor-functions, monotone-functions, constraints

I am looking for examples of monotonically increasing functions f(x) which can satisfy the following constraints:

- f(x=0) should be 0 and f(x>=25) should be 1.
- I want one or more parameters in the function to control the slope of the function.

The range of x is from 0 to 50.

I was thinking of tanh functions of the form - tanh(alpha*x -beta) for monotonically increasing functions, where alpha and beta are the parameters of the function.  But I don't know how to incorporate my constraint f(x=0) should be 0 and f(x>=25) should be 100.

Can you please help me with some examples of monotonically increasing functions which can satisfy my requirements?

Many thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options. You can use a function like $\min$.
So let's start as you did, with $f(x)=\tanh(x/c)$, where $c$ is a parameter to control the slope. We want to change this, so that $f(25)=1$. You need to multiply by a factor, so it will look like
$$f(x)=\frac{\tanh(x/c)}{\tanh(25/c)}$$
This $f(x)$ is greater than $1$. So you need to change it to $1$ for $x\ge 25$. You can do this with $\min$:
$$f(x)=\min\left(\frac{\tanh(x/c)}{\tanh(25/c)},1\right)$$
Alternatively, you can define the function piecewise, where you explicitly set the value to $1$ as $x\ge 25$. This one is more versatile, since you can choose any function in [0,25] that obeys your criteria. You can impose restrictions on the derivative at $0$ and $25$ for example.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the elegant solution! Really appreciate it!

Comment: A quick clarification. If I have a single parameter alpha or 1/c, then your solution works. If I have 2 parameters - alpha and beta to control the slope, how can I adapt your solution so that f(0)=0 and f(25)=1? Can you please help? Having two parameters alpha and beta in the tanh functions of the form tanh(alpha*x + beta) helps me to get a sigmoidal like f(x)  in the range 0 to 25 for non zero values of beta

Comment: The beta parameter will contradict your requirement that $f(0)=0$. Also, the beta parameter controls where is the center of the sigmoid. If you want something that increases slowly at 0, has the highest slope at beta, and the slope decreases towards 0 when $x\to25$, you would need to shift the function up. So I would start from $f(x)=\frac 12(1+\tanh(a x+b))$

Comment: Many thanks for the clarification, Andrei. In your original answer you mentioned that there are several options to achieve my requirement of f(x=0) should be 0 and f(x>=25) should be 1 and the function should have parameters to adjust the slope. Out of curiosity, what other options are there? Is there a general name to the class of functions that I am searching (a special case of monotonic functions)?

Comment: I was referring mostly to using $\min$ or to use cases. You can write the cases using Heaviside functions. But if you want a different case beside $\tanh$, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function has several options.

Comment: Appreciate your kind help, Andrei!